# How do I send a ping to keep connection to server alive using MessageWebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp

I'm using c# UWP and MessageWebSocket. In my app I need to send a ping to the server each 10 minutes to keep the webSocket connection alive.

But I really can't find any methods on the MessageWebSocket to send a ping, and google isn't much of a help here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocketcontrol.desiredunsolicitedponginterval?view=winrt-19041), `MessageWebSocketControl` contain `DesiredUnsolicitedPongInterval` that used to allow an app to get and set the desired unsolicited `WebSocket` PONG interval. And if you just want to keep the webSocket connection alive, please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTrigger?view=winrt-19041)

> See ControlChannelTrigger Remarks for details. The server keep-alive interval can be configured through ControlChannelTrigger’s [ServerKeepAliveIntervalInMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.ServerKeepAliveIntervalInMinutes) property while implementing application level PONGs.

**Update**

`MessageWebSocket` does not contain send a ping to server that used to keep connection alive. But you could use WebSocketKeepAlive class in conjunction with the `ControlChannelTrigger` class and related interfaces to enable real-time network status and triggers for the StreamWebSocket and MessageWebSocket classes in the UWP [`BackgroundTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response

I'm afraid it confused me even more, I'm working on the client part, and the client needs to send a ping to the server to keep the websocket alive, and as I understood the server will respond with a pong.

So the functionality you mentioned defines a PONG interval, not the PING interval.
I hope you have time to clarify it a bit more for me

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check update part,